# Inherit constructors with variadic arguments

Tags: c++, inheritance

I've got a simple class A with two constructors. One of them has veradic parameters. And class B is just the derived class and I want to instantiate class B using the derived constructors from class A.

Everything works until I want to use the special feature of variadic arguments. The last statement provokes an compiler error saying:

> ```
> "sorry, unimplemented: passing arguments to ellipsis of inherited constructor B::B(int, ...) [inherited from A]".
> ```

How can I fix that issue.

```
class A {
    public:
        A(float f){
            std::cout << "Do something" << std::endl;
        }

        A(int a, ...){
            std::cout << "Do something else" << std::endl;
        }
};

class B : public A {
    using A::A;
};

int main(){

    A a(2.0f); // works
    B b(1.0f); // works

    A c(1, 2, 3); // works
    B d(1); // works
    B e(1, 2); // doesn't work

    return 0;
}
```

The output would be:

```
Do something
Do something
Do something else
Do something else
ERROR :(
```

Comment: Unrelated: Your compiler tells you _"sorry"_ actually? What are you using?

Comment: I use the g++ statement to compile. `g++ -v` tells me: `gcc version 7.4.0`

Comment: He's using `gcc`. `clang 8.0.0` compiles this code without a problem.

Comment: So, is my only option to change the compiler?!

Comment: The GCC devs willfully chose not to implement this feature (yet). You can't change that, short of contributing to GCC yourself. So yes, changing compilers would be the only immediately available recourse.

Comment: It also reproduces that error with a [newer gcc version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9133b7fafb492386). I was just wondering about that kind of polite error message :-D.

Comment: If you still want to use GCC, have you looked at [variadic templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack)?

Comment: Mmh, ok. This is unfortunate though.  Do you have an advice?

Comment: Using veradic templates is sadly no option, because my real class already uses these.

Answer (score 1):

You need to inherit functions with variadic arguments seperately.

[EDIT]

```
class B : public A {
public:
    using A::A;
    B(int a, int ...) :A(a) {}
};
```

That way your constructor calls in `main()` would work flawlessly.

```
A a(2.0f); // calls A(float f)
B b(1.0f); // calls A(float f)

A c(1, 2, 3); // calls A(int a, ...)
B d(1); // calls A(int a, ...)
B e(1, 2); // calls A(int a, ...)
```

---

And the output would be:

```
Do something
Do something
Do something else
Do something else
Do something else
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I want to mention that [**Variadic arguments**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments) is a **C** language feature which just was inherited in C++ (and kept for compability).

Modern C++ provides type save alternatives like [**Parameter pack**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack), [**Initializer Lists**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) which IMHO should be preferred.

However, that said, now a possible solution.

I once found it when I tried to mimic something similar like `printf()`. At that time, I noticed the existance of [`vprintf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/vfprintf) and got why and for what it is good for.

This is the basic idea, I tried to solve the dilemma of OP:

```
#include <cstdarg>
#include <iostream>

class A {
  public:
    A(float f)
    {
      std::cout << "A::A(" << f << ")\n";
    }

    A(int n, ...)
    {
      std::cout << "A::A(";
      va_list args;
      va_start(args, n);
      getArgs(n, args);
      va_end(args);
      std::cout << ")\n";
    }
  protected:
    A()
    {
      std::cout << "A::A()\n";
    }

    void getArgs(int n, va_list args)
    {
      std::cout << n;
      for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        float arg = va_arg(args, double); // Please, note, float is not a standard argument type.
        std::cout << ", " << arg;
      }
    }
};

class B: public A {
  public:
    B(float f): A(f)
    {
      std::cout << "in B::B(float)\n";
    }

    B(int n, ...)
    {
      std::cout << "in B::B(";
      va_list args;
      va_start(args, n);
      getArgs(n, args);
      va_end(args);
      std::cout << ")\n";
    }
};

#define DEBUG(...) std::cout << #__VA_ARGS__ << ";\n"; __VA_ARGS__ 

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Test flavors of A::A():\n";
  DEBUG(A a1(1.23f));
  DEBUG(A a2(3, 1.2f, 2.3f, 3.4f));
  std::cout << "Test flavors of B::B():\n";
  DEBUG(B b1(1.23f));
  DEBUG(B b2(3, 1.2f, 2.3f, 3.4f));
}
```

Output:

```
Test flavors of A::A():
A a1(1.23f);
A::A(1.23)
A a2(3, 1.2f, 2.3f, 3.4f);
A::A(3, 1.2, 2.3, 3.4)
Test flavors of B::B():
B b1(1.23f);
A::A(1.23)
in B::B(float)
B b2(3, 1.2f, 2.3f, 3.4f);
A::A()
in B::B(3, 1.2, 2.3, 3.4)
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8b854a751b33d074)</kbd>

Hint:

An IMHO common trap with variadic arguments are the *default argument promotions*, mentioned e.g. here: [Variadic arguments – Default conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments#Default_conversions). (I remarked this with a resp. comment where it was relevant in my sample code.)

Comment: All of this was already clear to me. I just didn't want to write the constructor for ever new class deriving from A. But thanks nevertheless

Comment: You didn't wast my time :D. Probably I just wasn't clear enough about my issue. And your answer was great for others complaining about similar issues. I am always happy, when someone responds :D

Comment: @MoritzSeppelt It's not too late to refine your question. Just use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56098358/edit) link under your question... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

@Ekin: Your idea is great. The following code satisfies all my wishes (I just have to make a special case for the veradic constructor :D).

```
class B : public A {
public:
    using A::A; // Takes care of all normal constructors

    B(int a, int ...) :A(a) {}  // Takes care of the veradic constructor
};
```